# Can someone help figure out whats wrong with my answer on testdome?

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to the [question](https://www.testdome.com/questions/27781?generatorId=13&questionIds=26321%2C27781%2C23563&type=FromTest)

and here's my answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Spreadsheet</title>
    <style>

      td {
        text-align: right;
        width: 33%;
      }
      td, th, table {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th {
        text-align: left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>  
      <thead>
        <caption>Purchase Orders</caption>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Order Date</th>
          <th>SKU</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>07-16-2018</td>
          <td>523402</td>
          <td>54</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

It comes out fine on my IDE but on the website is saying 3 of 4 test cases fail.

Answer (score 3):

The site seems to be a little more strict here than to just check if it looks the same. To make the tests pass you need to:

1. Put the row containing the `<th>` tags between `<thead></thead>`.
2. Move the caption out of `<thead>`.

The correct code for the table would then look like this:

```
<table>
  <caption>Purchase Orders</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order Date</th>
      <th>SKU</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>07-16-2018</td>
      <td>523402</td>
      <td>54</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wow, lol thanks! something so simple. but I understand why I got it wrong now.